# How to show icon file in system tray?

Tags: java, desktop-application, system-tray, trayicon

I am adding my application in system tray when I close it. But it is not displaying the icon. When I try to show picture file then it works fine but when I try with an icon file it does not work. How can I display an icon instead picture?

```
Image image = new ImageIcon("src/resources/busylogo.jpg").getImage();
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
try {
  SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
} catch (AWTException e2) {
  e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What exceptions are you getting?

Comment: i am not getting any exception but its not displaying icon on tray

Comment: Try using, Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/busylogo.jpg");
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);

Comment: still no getting. i want to add .ico file instead .jpg

Comment: @Vinay common issue for Icon / ImageIcon that never returns exeptions on null, you have test for null instead

Comment: .ico file works good under windows only, are you using different OS?

Comment: i have tried both following codes but not getting yet,,1)Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/ChatIcon.ico");  2)Image image = new ImageIcon("src/resources/ChatIcon.ico").getImage();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use Toolkit to load an icon.
That's a low size file, and an asynchronous load will give you less problems.
Try this code, which is recommanded by Sun.

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/busylogo.jpg");
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
try {
   tray.add(trayIcon);
} catch (AWTException e2) {
   e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

More informations here : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

Comment: @Vinay just seen you last comment : not sure you can load .ico files. Didn't found for TrayIcon, but ImageIcon (for example) only accepts JGP/PNG/GIF (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html)

Comment: thanx. its working fine for .jpg but not for .ico and what i want is .ico

Comment: Confirmation, seems TrayIcon doesn't support ICO and BMP files. I guess it's because ICO is a Windows file format, so this can't be multiplatform (which is the Java main goal)

Comment: You can use this library to read Microsoft ICO file http://www.vdburgh.net/2/f/files/ICOReader/